# json/js/jquery how to filter multiple objects in nested json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im facing a small issue in filtering the data in dynamice nested json array. Can someone please help me to resolve my issue..

```
var data = {
    "root": {
        "children": [{
                "name": "Concept Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "20150101000000",
                    "endTime": "20150125000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Design Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015012500000",
                    "endTime": "20150311000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Validation Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015031100000",
                    "endTime": "20150430000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Production Preparation",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015043000000",
                    "endTime": "20150612000000"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Above json objects may increase dynamically. Now im trying to filter the JSON by passing multiple objects(`name,startTime,endTime`). Below is the code im trying..

```
var filterBy = {
                         name: ["Concept Phase"],
                         startTime:["20150101000000"],
                         endTime: ["20150125000000"]
                    };

var result = data.root.children.filter(function (o) {
                        return Object.keys(filterBy).every(function (k) {
                            return filterBy[k].some(function (f) {
                                return o[k] === f;
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

Above code will work if i pass only `name`. Because im filtering only upto `children`. How can i filter the properties that are available in `order`?

For the Above JSON i need to pass `name,startTime, endTime`. And the expected output should look like below..

```
data = {
    "root": {
        "children": [{
                "name": "Concept Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "20150101000000",
                    "endTime": "20150125000000"
                }]
            }
 ]
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can set exact object in filterBy variable as below

```
var filterBy = {
                         name: "Concept Phase",
                         order:[{
                    "startTime": "20150101000000",
                    "endTime": "20150125000000"
                }]
                    };
```

and then use below code to filter objects from children array

```
var result = data.root.children.filter(function (o) {
                        return JSON.stringify(o) === JSON.stringify(filterBy)
                    });
```

You also use underscore js functions _.isEqual to compare objects which is useful if order of key value pairs is different in original object

Answer (score 0):

You are using [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in the wrong way, I would suggest you read more about them to understand how they are used. So the issue with your [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function call is it return a function call instead of returning TRUE/FALSE value that's why its just in its just take the first element of `filterBy` object key array, to achieve what you want I would do it like:

```js
var data = {
    "root": {
        "children": [{
                "name": "Concept Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "20150101000000",
                    "endTime": "20150125000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Design Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015012500000",
                    "endTime": "20150311000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Validation Phase",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015031100000",
                    "endTime": "20150430000000"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Production Preparation",
                "order": [{
                    "startTime": "2015043000000",
                    "endTime": "20150612000000"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}

var filterBy = {
   name: ["Concept Phase"],
   startTime:["20150101000000"],
   endTime: ["20150125000000"]
};

var result = data.root.children.filter(function (o) {
    return o.name === filterBy.name[0] && o.order[0].startTime === filterBy.startTime[0] && o.order[0].endTime === filterBy.endTime[0];
});

console.log(result);
```